# Creating multidimensional Tuple array in C++/Cli

Tags: multidimensional-array, c++-cli

I use this line for creating a Tuple array:

```
Tuple<String^, double>^ t = gcnew Tuple<String^, double>("a", 2.6);
```

But how can I create a multidimensional array?

E.g.:

```
t[][] = {
        {"a", 2.6},
        {"b", 7.1},
        {"c", 2.4},
        {"d", 2.7}
};
```

Even if we do that, how can I get elements inside of array, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        textBox1->Text += t[i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx).

```
using namespace System;

int main()
{
  const unsigned rank = 2;
  const unsigned dim1 = 3;
  const unsigned dim2 = 4;

  auto arr = gcnew array<Tuple<String ^, double> ^, rank>(dim1, dim2);

  for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < dim2; j++)
      arr[i, j] = gcnew Tuple<String ^, double>("@_@", i * j);

  return 0;
}
```

`rank` is a dimensionality of array, so in this case it's a 2d array.

**UPD**

using aggregate initialization:

```
using elemT = Tuple<String ^, double>; // somewhere at top-level

  //...
  auto arr =
    gcnew array<elemT ^, rank>{{gcnew elemT{"@_@", 1.}, gcnew elemT{"^_^", 2.}},
                               {gcnew elemT{"~_~", 3.}, gcnew elemT{"+_+", 4.}}};
```

**UPD2**

As the mystery unveiled, OP didn't need multidimensional arrays, just an array of tuples:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using subarrT = array<double>;
using elemT   = Tuple<String ^, String ^, subarrT ^>;
int main()
{
  auto arr = gcnew array<elemT ^>{
    gcnew elemT{"Name1", "Surname1", gcnew subarrT{29., 123., 10., 1230.}},
    gcnew elemT{"Name2", "Surname2", gcnew subarrT{49., 32., 8., 256.}},
  };
  std::cout << static_cast<double>(arr[0]->Item3[1]) << std::endl; // 123.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can we initialize the arr values without using for loop?

Comment: Sorry about the bothering again. I connot managed to do this e.g: arr= {
        {"a", 2.6},
        {"b", 7.1},
        {"c", 2.4},
        {"d", 2.7}
};

Comment: Your last update is arr={ { {"a",1},{"b",2} },{ {"c",1},{"d",2} } }

Comment: First dimension store 4 secondary arrays and secondary dimesion store the string and double values. That is I'm trying to do

Comment: auto Tablo = gcnew array<elemT ^, 2>
  {
   {
    gcnew elemT{ "Kerem Kaçkar", "Antibiyotik", 29, 123, 10, 0 },
     gcnew elemT{ "Nergis Kara", "Serum", 49, 32, 8, 0 },
     gcnew elemT{ "Füsun Tuzcu", "Medikal", 23, 7, 11, 0 }
   }
  };

Comment: are you using vs2015?

Comment: No its visual s. 2013. In the last picture I did send; is there anything wrong?

Comment: in VS2013 some features may not work correctly. can you clarify what kind of structure do you need?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108603/discussion-between-trabolics-and-yuyoyuppe).